# Can't run Android instrumented (UI) tests with minifyEnabled

Tags: android, proguard, android-instrumentation

Currently my UI tests run fine with `minifyEnabled` set to false for debug builds. However I want to be able to run our UI tests with minifyEnabled but I'm getting the error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lkotlin/LazyKt;
at com.myapp.android.helpers.BaseUITest.<init>(BaseUITest.kt:89)
at com.myapp.android.helpers.BaseLoggedInUITest.<init>(BaseUITest.kt:58)
at com.myapp.android.BookingTest.<init>(BookingTest.kt:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:266)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:263)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:392)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2189)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "kotlin.LazyKt" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.mock.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.myapp.android.test-9ynAvfUfqJ1OtJ0zKiGLQw==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.myapp.android-jo1Vp8gfqma6NGH5xtf4nw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.myapp.android.test-9ynAvfUfqJ1OtJ0zKiGLQw==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.myapp.android-jo1Vp8gfqma6NGH5xtf4nw==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.myapp.android.test-9ynAvfUfqJ1OtJ0zKiGLQw==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.myapp.android-jo1Vp8gfqma6NGH5xtf4nw==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
```

The offending line is just the first line in the BaseUiTest class that uses Koin for dependency injection:

```
private val localPrefs: LocalPrefs by inject()
```

The build.gradle file looks like this:

```
buildTypes {
  debug {
    minifyEnabled true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    testProguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-test.pro'
  }
}
```

and I've tried every thing I can think of for the `proguard-test.pro` file, including:

```
-include proguard-rules.pro
-dontobfuscate
-dontwarn
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```

I don't understand why it can't resolve a Kotlin class `LazyKt`

Comment: Hi! Have you been able to solve this issue? We are also trying to do instrumented testing (androidTest) while the code is obfuscated (minifyEnabled true). We are also using reflection, and that mixture seems to be generating our NoClassDefFoundError. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately I never got it working. Such a shame because proguard bugs that UI tests don't catch with minify disabled are the most common ones.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing a very similar issue while I was too trying to run the UI tests with minification enabled.
My stacktrace looked like this:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lkotlin/LazyKt;
    at androidx.test.platform.io.OutputDirCalculator.<init>(OutputDirCalculator.kt:27)
    at androidx.test.platform.io.FileTestStorage.<init>(FileTestStorage.java:45)
    at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.registerTestStorage(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:664)
    at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:441)
    at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2361)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "kotlin.LazyKt" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.mock.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.base.jar", ...]]
```

And the solution was to add the following line to the proguard configuration file:

```
-keep public class kotlin.**
```